# Does one use WF and WCF together to build a messaging system?

Tags: wcf, workflow, messaging, eai

I am looking to build an messaging infrastructure to facilitate communications between different systems in our organization.  There are many way to go about this.  I have looked into nServiceBus and MassTransit.

How does WF/WCF fit into this - if at all? If it does, are there any good articles, documentation or books that focus on this type of solution specifically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This article covers design patterns for building a distributed service bus. It also has some limited coverage of how WCF and workflow are used in a service bus:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd334420.aspx

As an interlectual challenge it would be interesting to build a services. However, from a business cost benefit perspective it is probably not worth it. Especially when products like nServiceBus are free.

In addition to what you have looked at already, I would advise you to take a look at Azure .Net Service Bus:

http://www.microsoft.com/azure/servicebus.mspx